# Subscription expired: Most features of Excel will be disabled

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, subscription

I have delayed my subscription payment for Office 365 and they wrote me, that soon most features of Excel will be disabled.

What does it mean? That I will be unable to open my documents? That I need to pay forever to be able to see my own old documents I created many years ago?

How to get rid from this? Can I stop updates or something? Or the only way is to switch to another software vendor?

I understand that if I am not paying I wont get new features, but I am absolutely can't accept situation where I can't access my own old documents withput paying to somebody, so continuation of this is not an option for me.

Comment: You aren't paying your subscription for rolling updates, you are paying for *temporary access to the software*. In the same way that your entitlement to watch programs on Netflix ends at the same time as your subscription your access *to the software* will end with your subscription. This would have been spelled out in the terms of service you agreed to when you started the subscription. In the short term this method is cheaper than the "full" version and there is a reason for that.

Comment: Please don't feed me with this, the question was how to go out of these conditions, which I regard unacceptable.

Comment: That you find the terms unacceptable makes the choice simple. Purchase a product that has a perpetual licence as indicated by the answers below, or move products. How to bypass the licensing to get a paid product for free would be off topic here. Sadly in the world of streaming media and software this is not like a DVD where you have paid for the product and just want to remove copy protection. Microsoft used to have [Word Viewer](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/microsoft-office-word-viewer-b1772025-1ce0-4a66-ade9-154303e2a3ca) but they now send you to the online version.

Comment: Alternatively you can archive your documents by converting them to PDF or another format but you will loose any active or dynamic elements in them. I do genuinely feel for you, for a great many people Office 365 is *not* the product they want but it is a lot cheaper and easier to keep up to date than the perpetual version. There has also been a distinct lack of upfront discussion about what happens if your subscription lapses beyond "it stops working". It is made in a way that locks you in to their document system so that you either keep paying little bits or pay large for the other version.

Comment: Technically, comments are for requesting clarification, not for posting a full-length answer...

Answer (score 5):

Well, yes, "paying forever" is what a subscription-based service *is*.

If you're looking for a one-time purchase, that is called [Office 2019](https://products.office.com/en-us/get-started-with-office-2019). Older versions (Office 2016, maybe even Office 2010) might be also available from purchase from various stores. These products have the same applications as Office 365, but are  permanent purchases and work fully offline (except for the install-time license key check, that is). Documents are mostly backwards-compatible between versions.

Note: Some websites say that an Office 365 subscription *includes* an Office 2019 license, so if that's true and if you obtain the license before the  subscription expires, then that's your "stopping updates" option.

---

Here's the official Microsoft documentation on what happens [after Office 365 for Business expires](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/subscriptions-and-billing/what-if-my-subscription-expires?view=o365-worldwide):

> If you let your subscription expire, it goes through multiple states before it is ultimately deleted. […]
>
> State: Expired […] The expired state lasts for 30 days for most subscriptions […] 
>   In this state, users have normal access to the Office 365 portal, Office applications, and services
>
> State: Disabled […] If you don't reactivate your subscription while it is in the expired state, it moves into a disabled state, which lasts for **90 days** for most subscriptions […] Office applications eventually move into a **read-only,** reduced functionality mode and display Unlicensed Product notifications.
>
> State: Deprovisioned […] If you don't reactivate your subscription while it is in grace or disabled, the subscription is deprovisioned. Admins and users no longer have access to the services or Office applications that came with the subscription.

(The page also talks about permanent data deletion, this of course only applies to cloud storage and not to your local .doc/.xls files.)

Answer (score 1):

Office 365 is a subscription based service.  When you stop paying for the service, they have the right to disable all or part of your access to the service.  Whatever the agreement entails was in the license agreement you accepted.

What will happen?  I dont know.  I have not read the agreement in years and I am sure it has changed - and will probably change again.  However, I would ***ASSUME*** the ability to read and possibly do minor edits will remain after the service is ended.

Why do I ***ASSUME*** that?  Well that brings me to my first possible solution. Microsoft gives the ability to create and edit Office documents for free on the [web](https://www.office.com/), as well as in their [iOS](https://products.office.com/en-us/mobile/office-mobile-apps-for-ios) and [Android](https://products.office.com/en-us/mobile/office-mobile-apps-for-android) apps.  These options have many features, they dont have all the functionality in the paid versions.  Therefore, they may or may not work for you.  You would have to test them to see if they have the capabilities you need.

Alternatively, you can purchase a non subscription based version of Microsoft Office.  [Office 2019](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-s-the-difference-between-office-365-and-office-2019-ed447ebf-6060-46f9-9e90-a239bd27eb96) is a full version of Office, that is yours forever for a one time payment.

Other options include moving to a different, yet [compatible office suite](https://www.techradar.com/news/the-best-free-office-software).  Some of the options are free of charge, while others do have a fee, but are less than Microsoft Office.  The only drawback to these suites is the *level* of compatibility may differ.  You would have to test your office documents to make sure they work properly in these suites.